# convert hexstring to hexadecimal bytes without using in c without libraries

Tags: c, embedded

I have a string `{F0A9B8BDE38182}`
I need to convert it to hexadecimal bytes

```
0xF0 0xA9 0xB8 0xBD 0xE3 0x81 0x82
```

I am able to get answer with the below code

```
for (i = 0; i < (str_len /2); i++)
{
    sscanf(hexstring + 2*i, "%02x", &bytearray[i]);
    printf("bytearray %d: %02x\n", i, bytearray[i]);
}
```

but I need without using `sscanf`

Comment: You just need to convert the digits.  If you know they're ANSI characters, then check for the range `'0'` through `'9'`, in which case subtract `'0'` to get the digit value, and the range `'A'` through `'F'`, in which case subtract `'A'` and add 10.  Check for lowercase too if you need to.

Comment: C standard library has [other conversion functions too](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul), which don't require `stdio.h`.

Comment: `int h2i(int x) { switch (x) { default: return 0; case '1': return 1; /*...*/ case 'F': return 15; }`

Comment: [see ideone for a running example](https://ideone.com/GAsggA)

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert individual `ASCII` to respective `HEX` digit, then use `|` to form the complete `byte`.

**Example:**

```
   for (i = 0; i < strlen(s)/2; i++)
    {
       bytearray[i] = AsciiToHex(s[2*i])<<4 | AsciiToHex(s[2*i+1]);
       printf("bytearray %d: %02X\n", i, bytearray[i]);
    }

    uint8_t AsciiToHex(char c){

       if (c >= '0' && c<='9') return c - '0';
       else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return 10 + c - 'A';
       else return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I want to change a hex string to hexadecimal.i donot want to convert ascii to hex

Comment: @user10331124 that is what it is doing, in order to convert hex-string to hexadecimal you need to convert each ascii char to respective hex digit.

Comment: @user10331124, This does what you want. `AsciiToHex` is just misnamed. It converts an ASCII character *from* hex to a number (0..15). Then the caller combines pairs of these numbers into larger numbers (0..255 or -128..127 depending on the system's definition of `char`), the bytes you requested.

Comment: `AsciiToHex()` only works with character sets that use ordered sequences of character definitions like ASCII. But not all execution character sets are ASCII. Another possible solution will use a character array like `char hex_chars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";` and lookup the character to convert.

Comment: hey Kiran,thank you so much this worked.Please do let me know how to do hex to bytestring as well as im new to this and I want to know.

Comment: @user10331124 You need to ask one more question as the new question is too board to answer as part of this question.